# How to create DSN in Ingres using Ubuntu?

Tags: php, odbc, ingres, actian

I got the message error below when i try to test the DSN.

- I verified the Path of the driver
- I verified the permission of the driver

Could someone know what mean this error or any Ideas for the solution?

[image: Error Message]

Comment: "$II_SYSTEM/ingres/sig/errhelp/errhelp 67620" gives: "The specified dynamic library does not exist". I'm not sure if that also writes the name of the file it can't find to errlog.log. If it doesn't, maybe run it again with strace (eg: "strace your_command 2> alogfile") and see if the trace log helps to identify the failed attempt to open a file.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I fix  the issue. Now I have connected php 7.2 to ingres with odbc using a DSN, installing Client Runtime for Linux. It's working fine in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Write the solution, and accept it, so others who may encounter the same problem know what to do.